# custom title bar for NSWindow

Tags: xcode, macos

I have been trying to create a custom title bar for NSWindow, following the help of [Creating a custom title bar on a standard NSWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658044/creating-a-custom-title-bar-on-a-standard-nswindow).

```
NSView *themeFrame = [[window contentView] superview];
NSView *firstSubview = [[themeFrame subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[titleBarView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewMinYMargin | NSViewWidthSizable)];
[themeFrame addSubview:titleBarView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:firstSubview];
```

It works well for OSX 10.9, but in OSX 10.10, Xcode posts a waring:

```
NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview:XXX
0   AppKit                              0x00007fff88f80b3c -[NSThemeFrame addSubview:] + 107
1   AppKit                              0x00007fff8896fb8f -[NSView addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 208
```

The app can run well and show the customised title, and this warning only shows in Xcode console.
So does OSX 10.10 make some changes here? And any new methods to add custom title bar?

Comment: Is making a custom title bar a good idea? As a user I appreciate consistency.

Comment: Thanks guy, yes, we'd better make the most of original UI in our app. I just found https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow, and tried it myself, but don't know why this problem comes in OSX 10.10.

Comment: If you're on OS X Yosemite trying to use ```INAppStoreWindow```, which is a great piece of software, consider switching to ```WAYAppStoreWindow``` instead. It's a wrapper that chooses the correct NSWindow subclass at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I will try WAYAppStoreWindow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, OS X Yosemite uses a new NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController API for adding custom subviews to the titlebar:

> NSWindow has never supported clients adding subviews to anything other than the contentView. Some applications would add subviews to the contentView.superview (also known as the border view of the window). NSWindow will now log when it detects this scenario: "NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview:". Applications doing this will need to fix this problem, as it prevents new features on 10.10 from working properly. See titlebarAccessoryViewControllers for official API.
>
> NSWindow now has the ability to add officially known subviews to the titlebar/toolbar area. The views are to be wrapped with a new NSViewController subclass called NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController and added to the window with the "titlebarAccessoryViewControllers" API. There are a set of methods to add and insert the titlebarAccessoryViewControllers, such as addTitlebarAccessoryViewController: and removeTitlebarAccessoryViewControllerAtIndex:. However, one can also utilize "removeFromParentViewController" to easily remove a given child view controller. NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController has a property to tell NSWindow where to place the view (layoutAttribute) and a property to determine how it behaves in full screen (fullScreenMinHeight). The NSToolbar fullScreenAccessoryView API is now deprecated, and clients should utilize this new API.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/